# Android - Preference - How to get os settings style in preference screen for my app

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I couldn't quite figure out how to achieve the shadow separator as with Lollipop os settings in my app's settings screen. Please see the screenshot below.

I know I can use a simple custom preference with a shadow drawable to get this look. But I wish to know if there is any built-in native way of doing this in android L and later.

Please help...

[image]

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find any option other than to insert a non interactive custom Preference just to display this shadow :(

Comment: huh okay - it's funny how they decide to do something like this in the system settings, when there don't appear to be other than hackish solutions - thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the same and, as it turns out that this is just a matter of setting "elevation" of the Viewgroups above and below.

I set elevation as 5dp for both the top and bottom ViewGroups and provided a margin of 10dp between them to get similar results.

Ofcourse its available only from L onwards. But I see that its L settings screenshot that you have provided.

Answer (score 0):

@Androbean Studio is right. Checkout the Settings source. It create ui by [DashboardSummary#rebuildUI](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/src/com/android/settings/dashboard/DashboardSummary.java).There is a view named categoryView with its [xml layout](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings/blob/master/res/layout/dashboard_category.xml). You will find the [elevation](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-cn/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:elevation) attr in the LinearLayout.